# Mostrar una tabla mysql con JOIN y valores NULL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql base, dónde están los registros de todos los equipos (es para una página de fútbol) necesito emparejarla con dos tablas pero sólo contando unos valores. Por ejemplo:

Tabla base llamada "equipos", dónde se van a sacar los demás datos

```
id      equipo
(int)   (varchar)  
-------------------
afc     Aragua
ccs     Caracas
dan     Anzoátegui
```

Esta tabla es la que quiero emparejar llamada "datos".

```
id      equipo1      equipo2       data3
(int)   (varchar)   (varchar)       (int)
-------------------------------------
1       dan           ccs         456
2       ccs           dan         654
3       ccs           dan         666
```

Entonces he tratado con:

```
SELECT eq.id, eq.equipo, count(dat1) AS dato1, count(dat2) AS dato2 
FROM equipos AS eq 
INNER JOIN datos AS dat1 ON dat1.equipo1 = eq.id 
INNER JOIN datos AS dat2 ON dat2.equipo2 = eq.id 
GROUP BY eq.id 
ORDER BY eq.equipo ASC
```

Sé que no funciona así, pero quisiera que quedara algo como esto:

```
equipo      dato1      dato2
-------------------------------
dan           1          2
ccs           2          1
afc           0          0
```

El problema que tengo es que el valor afc no aparece es NULL en la base de datos "datos" entonces no aparece en la búsqueda.

Comment: lo correcto es utilizar sentencias left outer join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar sub-consultas, de esta manera:

```
select   eq.id
       , (select count(1) from datos AS d where d.equipo1 = eq.id) as dato1
       , (select count(1) from datos AS d where d.equipo2 = eq.id) as dato2
  from equipos as eq
```

Comment: Hola jachguate, te dejo un enlace que demuestra tu consulta si deseas usarla: http://rextester.com/FPZ90750.

Comment: gracias @sstan, por lo que veo hay una alternativa a sqlfiddle, que por ahora siempre está roto!

Comment: Sí, llevo rato notando que SQLFiddle no funciona bien. Aunque rextester tiene sus fallas también, por ahora funciona mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Por la razón misma que pueden faltar ciertos equipos en la tabla `datos`, es necesario que uses un `LEFT JOIN`.

Aquí te dejo una forma de hacer la consulta:

```
select eq.id, 
       eq.equipo,
       coalesce(d1.cnt, 0) as dato1,
       coalesce(d2.cnt, 0) as dato2
  from equipos eq
  left join (select equipo1, count(*) as cnt
               from datos
              group by equipo1) d1
    on d1.equipo1 = eq.id
  left join (select equipo2, count(*) as cnt
               from datos
              group by equipo2) d2
    on d2.equipo2 = eq.id
 order by eq.equipo
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/QXAYZ75440).

**Edición**

Notarás que @jachguate te dio una buena respuesta también para tu situación. Y si tienes poquitos datos, no importa mucho cual consulta uses. Pero si tienes una mayor cantidad de datos, te animo a comparar el rendimiento. Normalmente, usar los joins debería resultar en mejor rendimiento que usar sub consultas, pero te tocará hacer la prueba para verificar.

Comment: Sobre lo que comentas del rendimiento, en casos como este, que difícilmente habrá millones de equipos registrados, suelo recomendar no preocuparse demasiado por realizar consultas óptimas y si un poco más por realizar consultas fáciles de entender (y por tanto de mantener). Es la razón por la que propongo una solución como la de [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/37936/21), ya que me parece que el objetivo queda más claro. Luego, ya será más o menos óptima dependiendo del motor y su configuración.

Comment: Algunos motores internamente cambiarán la sub-consulta por un join, con lo cual el rendimiento será prácticamente el mismo. Ya luego, si en la práctica la consulta es lenta, entonces ya se aprietan las tuercas donde debe ser para tener un rendimiento óptimo. Creo que la ganancia en general es sustanciosa manteniendo este enfoque, pues terminas con una aplicación más fácil de mantener. Ya ves que dicen que escribir software es como tener sexo... cargas con cada error que cometes durante el resto de tu vida, jajajaja.

Comment: @jachguate: muy razonable lo que dices, gracias. Y esa expresión nunca la había oído :)

Comment: Otra en la que pienso siempre al escribir software, es que la persona que le dará mantenimiento dentro de 5 años es un psicópata, y que sabe donde vivo. Por eso, siempre, siempre, primero me esfuerzo en escribir código mantenible. Una vez leí que cualquier tonto puede escribir código que la máquina puede interpretar, pero no cualquiera puede escribir código que otro humano pueda entender.

Comment: yo considero que esta es la respuesta correcta, los selects anidados, no son considerados buenas practicas en ningún lugar, ademas la información esta mal, mi sugerencia generar tablas donde se pueda obtener la información de la manera correcta, siempre usar joins, el día que trabajen en un banco, tendrán un manual de lo que se puede y no se puede hacer, saludos!